# result of web service?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

i wrote a code using SOAP function to get from web service , the problem is that the response is not an xml string , what i need to know , the error from my android code SOAP function ? or from web service ? 
why the result is liske this

```
 public String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://tempuri.org/GetDataTable";

    public String OPERATION_NAME2 = "GetDataTable";

    public String SOAP_ADDRESS2 = "http://192.168.0.15/EServicedesk/DesktopModules/EServiceDesk.Website/ESDWebService/Auth.asmx?WSDL";
Object response;
String XMLData = null;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
    SoapRequestTask2 task;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        task = new SoapRequestTask2();
        try { 
            XMLData = task.execute().get();
            Log.i("task ", XMLData);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

private class SoapRequestTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        // runs on ui thread.
        private String data;

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        // runs in the background thread. do not update ui from here
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                    OPERATION_NAME2);
            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("UserID");
            pi.setValue(193);
            pi.setType(Integer.class);
            request.addProperty(pi);


            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS2);

            response = null;
            try {
                // httpTransport.debug=true;
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);
                // String ss = httpTransport.requestDump;
                response = envelope.getResponse();

                data = response.toString();
            //  Log.i("respons", envelope.getResponse().toString());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                response = exception.toString();
                XMLData = response.toString();
            }

            return data;
        }
```

here is the result :
task 2: anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyRequests; Count=927; }; TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyAssignedRequests; Count=603; }; TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyServiceDeskRequests; Count=969; }; TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyWorkGroupRequests; Count=770; }; TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyApproval; Count=82; }; }; }; }

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

Web service returns array of object

you can get value for each value for each object by going to perticular node then use getProperty() method to get value for required object  as follow.
//old web services.

```
public void  getLocation()
{
    OPERATION_NAME = "GetLd";   
    SOAP_ACTION = Constants.strNAMESPACE+""+OPERATION_NAME;     
        REQUST_ID=3;
        final Responce responce=new Responce();
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {

            SoapObject response;                
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                SoapObject request=new SoapObject(Constants.strNAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.strWEB_SERVICE_URL);
                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                if(response!=null)
                {
                     SoapObject str = null;
                        for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++)
                                str=(SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);       


                        SoapObject str1 = (SoapObject) str.getProperty(0);

                        SoapObject str2 = null;
                        ArrayList<Location> arrData=new ArrayList<Location>();
                        for(int j=0;j<str1.getPropertyCount();j++)
                        {                       
                            str2 = (SoapObject) str1.getProperty(j);
                            Location location=new Location();
                            if(str2!=null)
                            {   
                                responce.Result_Type=Constants.DataPresent;

                                if(isValidProperty(str2, "LocationName"))
                                {
                                    location.setName(str2.getProperty("LocationName").toString());
                                }
                                if(isValidProperty(str2, "LocationId"))
                                {
                                    location.setId(Integer.parseInt(str2.getProperty("LocationId").toString()));
                                }   
                                arrData.add(location);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                responce.Result_Type=Constants.NoDataPresent;
                            }                               
                        }
                        responce.ResponceData=arrData;
                        Log.d("Location", "------------------------");
                        for(int i=0;i<arrData.size();i++)
                            Log.d("Tag", arrData.get(i).toString());
                      }
                }          
                catch (Exception e) 
                {       
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    responce.Result_Type=Constants.Error;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Message message=new Message();
                    message.what=REQUST_ID;
                    message.arg1=responce.Result_Type;
                    message.obj=responce;               
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }       
            }

        });
        thread.start();
}







 boolean isValidProperty(SoapObject soapObject,String PropertyName)
    {
        if(soapObject!=null)
        {
            if(soapObject.hasProperty(PropertyName))
            {
                if(!soapObject.getProperty(PropertyName).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")&&!soapObject.getProperty(PropertyName).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("anyType{}"))
                    return true;
            else
                return false;
            }
            return false;

        }
        else
            return false;

    }
```

Comment: #shivaji
this is not working always give me propertycount one

Comment: why it is not xml output ?

Comment: you need to check where you actual data start and start parsing from that node and skip other unwanted node..

Comment: as in my example where i should start ?

Comment: please help me really i need this

Comment: asma can provide me link for webseravice so that i can give you exact method with output...

Comment: i can't its just locally :(

Comment: output is as i wrote above , but i can't parse it

Comment: can you send me xml output of your websrvice

Comment: execute your webservice in browser and check its xml out put and send thatouput..

Comment: anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyRequests; Count=927; }; TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyAssignedRequests; Count=603; }; TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyServiceDeskRequests; Count=969; }; TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyWorkGroupRequests; Count=770; }; TargetTable=anyType{RequestHotList=MyApproval; Count=82; }; }; }; }

Comment: this is not brower ouput this out from android device

Comment: this what i need to parse

Comment: if you need xml its laarge this is a part from it 
- <VwRequest diffgr:id="VwRequest29" msdata:rowOrder="28" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
  <RequestId>930</RequestId> 
  <RequestCode>INC 000000930</RequestCode> 
  <ServiceId>34</ServiceId> 
  <CategoryId>5</CategoryId> 
  <LastModifiedDate>2010-11-23T16:18:37.877-08:00</LastModifiedDate>

Comment: <Weight>3</Weight> 
  <WorkgroupId>43</WorkgroupId> 
  <CreatedBy>212</CreatedBy> 
  <ServiceDeskId>10</ServiceDeskId> 
  <LastModifiedBy>212</LastModifiedBy> 
  <OwnerCompanyId>1</OwnerCompanyId> 
  <Summary>test</Summary> 
  <Description>teasfasdf <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">asdf

Comment: </span><br style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">asdf</span><br style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">a</span><br style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">sd</span><br><div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<br>qsfasdf asdfasd <br></div></Description> 
  <CultureId>en-US</CultureId> 
  <WorkgroupName>IT Center</WorkgroupName>

Comment: <TeamLeaderId>193</TeamLeaderId> 
  <TeamLeaderFullName>Peter Abu Zulof</TeamLeaderFullName> 
  <OwnerUserId>193</OwnerUserId> 
  <RequestTyepId>1</RequestTyepId>